# How far is the heat limit from the power limit on speedlights?

Tags: flash, battery

Sort of questioning the premise of [What to look for in a flash battery pack?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65179/27832): Can a speedlight work significantly faster than on its internal batteries without overheating?

The reason I ask is that I've been running my speedlights on Gen-2 Eneloops.  Sure, if I want to run full-power it takes a couple of seconds to recharge.  But I *imagine* that if I cycled at full-power much more quickly I'd overheat the flash after not too many shots.  My solution has been to buy the highest-power speedlights I can and run them at no more than 1/8 power.  At that level even on internal batteries they can keep up with my 12fps body, and I almost never overheat.

I suppose that for shorter or less-frequent bursts it could be useful to shoot full power with fast cycle times.  So:

1. How much faster can speedlights run on the best power inputs?
2. How long can they run at maximum speed before overheating?

I imagine this would be something like a table showing full-power cycle speed for each power source along with the number sequential full-power shots at that speed before hitting thermal limit.)

Comment: why not using continuous lighting ? Do you need to decompose a motion ?

Comment: @Olivier: Because I can't afford or carry a continuous light and power source with output anywhere near the levels I want and can easily get from a flash.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is very difficult to answer.

> I imagine this would be something like a table showing full-power cycle speed for each power source along with the number sequential full-power shots at that speed before hitting thermal limit.)

There is no table that can be found or created to display this kind of information, on a general scale. This is because of the specification and construction for every flash is completely different. The materials, quality and circuit type of a flash can greatly affect and change the number of possible shots before overheat.

In regards to buying the highest power flash, the most powerful guide number flash that I'm aware of is GN60/GN58 (at ISO 100) which is held by the the flagship Canon/Nikon flashes.

[image: New Metz Digital Flash]

You might find that something like a Metz flash or a Godox Wistro might have more power, however as a consequence you sacrifice size and portability.

[image: Godox Wistro Flash]

Just because you have a higher power flash dosen't necessarily mean that you can shoot at certain power levels for longer. This is a direct consequence of how the flash is designed to dissipate heat and channel the flash's power.

I would suggest that you try renting/borrowing several different flashes from various manufacturers and then comparing their  performance.

You could of course try a more creative DIY approach which would involve adding external heatsinks and increased airflow in order to reduce the heat of the flash.

> At that level even on internal batteries they can keep up with my 12fps body, and I almost never overheat.

By using the internal batteries of the flash,you are limiting the possible recharge speed of the flash. This will slow the flash down and not allow it to keep up with your 12fps body.

> Can a speedlight work significantly faster than on its internal batteries without overheating?

Theoretically a flash can work indefinitely if the optimal power level is found. Aka you have found the balance between the flashes power and heat created.

A worthy note is that continuous lighting can be incredibly effective. Especially when using lights that utilise LEDs.

Comment: Thanks, some good points here.  NB: I wasn't *guessing*, I was *observing* that my flashes at 1/8 power running on internal Gen2 Eneloop AAs *do keep up* with 12fps shooting.

Comment: Interesting what flashes do you use? :)

Comment: This is with a couple of $60 Neewer NW TT660 II flashes, backed up by a relatively weak Sony F43.  (I typically set key and fill with the Neewers, and I have the Sony as background/hair light.)

Comment: Have you tried the new Neewer TT860? It uses a new Lithium Ion battery which means it recycles from full power in about a second.

Comment: BTW, since you're the second person to recommend LED continuous lighting: Are portable continuous LED panels really capable of approaching the power of a speedlight?  Last time that question was asked the answer seemed to be no: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34225/27832

Comment: I would say flash is still more powerful however I bought some 5630 LEDs and they are incredibly bright to the point where they could be comparable to a speedlite. LEDs are interesting because the technology is constantly developing and becoming even more powerful!

Comment: Haven't tried the Li-ion Neewers.  That's part of why I'd like to see data on this question: Of course it's great if we're just popping a few flashes and heat buildup isn't a consideration.  But I'd like to be able to reference the heat/cycle-rate/light-output for different applications.  And then one could also bring the LED panels into the question in an intelligent fashion.

Comment: Have a look at this YouTube video: https://youtu.be/c--5c3Egv4E it shows a DIY flash light using a high powered LED. It's probably a little large but it still gives you a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps you could obtain the data by asking the community to perform various tests on different flashes and then collate the results?

Comment: Wow: That LED has amazing output!  Kind of funny how it's basically a giant heat sink with a tiny panel on one side and battery on the other.  Asking the community for data seems like a great idea to me.  I asked on meta why not http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/4846/27832 and I expect we'll be reminded shortly ;)

Comment: It is kinda ridiculous! And hopefully people can provide data for lots of different setups and flashes!

Answer (score 0):

**Test protocol:** Start with fully-charged power supply.  Start with "cold" flash – i.e., having rested at ambient room temperature.  Don't put modifiers on or in front of flash that could increase heat retention.

- **Pops to overheat** is number of sequential full-power pops that will trip thermal cutoff.
- **Cycle time** is *time elapsed from start of test until cutoff* divided by *number of pops* fired during test.

Pop flash as fast as it recharges until it hits thermal cutoff.

```
LightSource       Guide #    Power Supply      Cycle Time   Pops to overheat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sony FM-43          43       Gen2 Eneloop AA     0.875s     39
Neewer TT 660 II    58       Gen2 Eneloop AA     2.250s     60 [Note 1]
```

- *Note 1:* Stopped test when flash began to emit burning smell.  Manual claims it has thermal protection but also warns against more than 10 sequential pops without allowing 15 minutes to cool.